# AWS Step Functions: returning a substring of a placeholder in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a SageMaker TrainingStep followed by a ProcessingStep. I need to pass the output path of the TrainingStep to the ProcessingStep.

The TrainingStep is writing the output to an S3 folder into a file named `s3://mybucket/output.tar.gz`. But, as output, in the path `$['ModelArtifacts']['S3ModelArtifacts']`, it is returning a wrong file name: `s3://mybucket/model.tar.gz`

To be able to work around this bug, I have to remove the last 12 characters of the path. So the Amazon States Language expression I need to run is:

```
$['ModelArtifacts']['S3ModelArtifacts'][0,-12]
```

I am using Python to configure my state machine, so I have the following code:

```
ProcessingInput(
  source=
    train_step.output()["$['ModelArtifacts']['S3ModelArtifacts'][0,-12]"], 
  destination='/opt/ml/processing/inference_output/',
  input_name='inference_output'
),
```

Which generates the following Amazon States Language string:

```
        "S3Input": {
          "S3Uri.$": "$['$['ModelArtifacts']['S3ModelArtifacts'][0,-12]']",
          "LocalPath": "/opt/ml/processing/inference_output/",
          "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
          "S3InputMode": "File",
          "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
          "S3CompressionType": "None"
        }
```

Which is not the desired result, because the desired result is to produce the following:

```
"S3Uri.$": "$['ModelArtifacts']['S3ModelArtifacts'][0,-12]"
```

How can I modify my Python code to produce the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around is to specify the correct S3 path as an *Execution input* parameter.